# Exception Value: invalid type for argument text

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm trying to get a paragraph with `reportlab` but I can't get it to work.

This code works fine:

```
p.setFont('Helvetica',8)
labo = str('CANCIÓN').decode('utf-8')
p.setFillColor(HexColor('#ff8100'))
p.drawString(350,736, labo)
```

But this code doesn't:

```
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
labo = Paragraph("Generating Reports with Python", styles["Heading1"])
p.drawCentredString(400,600, labo)
```

It returns:

```
Exception Value:    invalid type for argument text
```

What am I doing wrong?

I think I have imported all necessary modules.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from django.http import HttpResponse
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.colors import HexColor
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader

from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph

import os
from io import BytesIO
import PIL.Image

from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is that you are mixing up syntax. `Paragraph` is used in `Platypus` while `drawCentredString` is a basic canvas operation.

The syntax for `drawCentredString` is `canvas.drawCentredString(x, y, text)` which expects you to feed it text as a `string`, so not a `Paragraph` object.

The syntax for `Paragraph` is different, it is supposed to look like this:

```
p = Paragraph("Generating Reports with Python", styles["Heading1"])        
p.wrapOn(canvas, 200, 400)
p.drawOn(canvas, 400, 600)
```

So after we make the paragraph, we tell it how much space it can use using `wrapOn`. And after that we use `drawOn` to draw it on to the canvas.

But doing it the way mention aboved uses only a really small part of the power of `Platypus` (and thus `Paragraph`). It can be used to handle to complete flow of your document instead of only a single `Paragraph`, so you might want to check out chapter 5 of the [Reportlab Userguide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) which explains it usage and benefits in a clear way.